# How to clear registry manually in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have installed postgreSQL in my pc.

Unfortunately, it doesn't connecting database.

Now, at my reinstalling, the same problem occurs. This can be solved by cleaning registry.

Can I clear it manually ?

Comment: How come did you conclude that the problem will be solved by cleaning (or related to) the registry?

Comment: Let me say this: Have a nice time breaking your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*A word of warning:* Be *very* careful with editing the registry! It may turn your Windows installation unusable pretty fast.

Now that this is out of the way:

1. Open the Windows start menu.
2. Enter `regedit` in the search field (Vista/7) or the "run command" field (XP)
3. Enjoy. You can search the registry (Edit > Search) for strings containing "postgres".

However, I agree to Mehper, that you should first find out *what* to change exactly before just digging through the registry.